# I am sending two strings from the server, and my host is reading both the strings as one. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing, queue

My server is continuously sending a string to my host `String1 = '{a:1, b:2}'` and `String2 = '{a:4, b:5}'`

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
PORT = 65432        

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

But my host is receiving two strings as one string `{a:1, b:2}{a:4, b:5}`

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
```

I want to loose no data, and neither I can compromise with the speed. Kindly suggest some solutions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you literally sending `String1 = '{a:1, b:2}'` or just `{a:1, b:2}`. I would expect the latter given your result. You are telling your server to read the next 1024 bytes of input. So unless the first thing you send is exactly 1024 bytes, `data` *is* going to be one string. Either detect the separate parts of the string, or make sure to send a newline character, and split on that.

Comment: ohh okay thanks, and ya I am sending it as string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python socket receiving multiple messages at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408098/python-socket-receiving-multiple-messages-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrote two strings to a file and gave it to somebody, how would they know where the first string ends and the next string starts?  That's how sockets work, too.

You have to buffer your data and implement a method extract the separate strings.  That could be done by sending a byte indicating the size of the string first, or separate them by a character that won't appear in the string (null, newline, etc.).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409587/235698) for another solution.